# Pyspark distinct return two equal values

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, distinct

I have a really strange problem. I have read a csv-file where some columns has both NULL and null values. I tried to find columns that have the same values on each row but ended up with this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col, trim
df.select(trim(lower(col("COLNAME")))).distinct().show()

+-------------------------------+
|trim(lower(COLNAME))|
+-------------------------------+
|                           null|
|                           null|
+-------------------------------+
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

When looking closer at the values, I saw that one of the values was the string "null" and the other the actual `NULL` value. That's why they didn't count as the same value.